# How to fix this on glitch

Tags: python, flask

i get this error when i try to ru my flask app on glitch. I really dont know what is wrong with that line of code it says error. Help please!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "agrohelper.py", line 6, in 
    country = input("Enter your city name : ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Welcome Josias! Please share the rest of the agrohelper.py file, as well as more of the stack trace of the error. As of now we don't know what that line of code is doing without seeing more.

Comment: this is link to github repo : https://github.com/JosiasAurel/AgroHelper/blob/master/agrohelper.py

Comment: this is the error i get on glitch : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in <module>
    country = input("Enter your city name : ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: how are you running the program? `input()` is used for terminal input, but this appears to be a web server you are running indirectly from `server.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that when you start the flask server, which will call your `agrohelper.py` file, and the server startup method doesn't expect the `input()` function to stop and hang, waiting for the user to input a value. The result is that the `input()` function immediately returns without any input or bytes read. 
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError

If you want to build an app that has user input you may want to look at a forms plugin like `Flask-WTF`: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

If you are wanting to build a test script to pick a country, try reading a static data file such as the [`data.json` you already have.](https://github.com/JosiasAurel/AgroHelper/blob/master/data.json)